# In a Blazor Web App (.NET 8), links do not change scroll position

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, scroll, blazor

I have this strange new scrolling behavior in Blazor (Web App, Interactive render mode = Server) with .NET8.

When clicking on a link, the scroll position is not changed. If a link is clicked far down on a page, the new page is opened on the same scroll position and the user would then have to scroll up himself to see the top of the page. This was not the case with .NET <= 7 / Blazor Server Side.

One workaround I have found so far is to work with an anchor link (e.g. insert `<span id ="top"></span>` at the top of each page and then add '#top' to all links). But I understandably want to avoid that.

Here's a small repo: https://github.com/Sabbi/BlazorScroll

Just click on the link on the bottom of the page (you should need to scroll down to see it), then the new page is dispayed not from the top.

Any idea how to fix this?

**[Update]:**

In App.razor, I've changed  `<Routes />` to `<Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />`.
Now scrolling is as expected, at the cost that Blazor opens a Websocket-Connection now (which I wanted to avoid since there are no interactive components on the page).

As it behaves different on different rendermodes, I assume it's even more a bug than a feature.

Comment: same, probably should file a bug report. they had similar bug back in the early days of blazor as well

Comment: this is usually desired behavior in SPAs... it's harder to restore a previous scroll position than it is to scroll to the top.  (you can use window.scrollTo(0,0) to scroll to the top if needed)

Comment: Hi @Sabbi, this is new feature and expected behavior in .NET 8, if you want to scroll to top, you may need use js code to achieve your requirement. More details you could refer to this github issue:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40190#issuecomment-1203857906

Comment: Hi @Rena , the github does IMHO not describe the same issue. My issue is with normal 'a href'-Links pointing to other pages, not with the NavigationManager.

Comment: This is basic functionality of how web site link clicks work and should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get your desired behaviour by adding this data attribute on your links:
data-enhance-nav="false"
This tells Blazor not to use enhanced navigation on those links.